# PHP How to run script automatically

Tags: php

I have a simple API which is calling data from API and saves it in  a file

```
<?php 

ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://runapi.php?offset=0&limit=500');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');

$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);

file_put_contents('cache.json', $query);

curl_close($curl_handle);

?>
```

I save it in server and simply run it in a browser. However I want it to run automatically, I've read somewhere it could be done by cron job. The problem is that I am not using Cpanel. Can anyone tell me how solve that?

Comment: _“but i am not using Cpanel”_ - that is not a requirement for using cron. We have no idea what system you are on - so do some research yourself, and figure out if your system offers cron functionality, and if so, where/how to configure it.

Comment: If you are on Linux/Unix then you have CRON, all you need to do is look it up in the man pages

Answer (score 0):

You can use cronjob, CRON or online cron services (e.g easycron.com)